# Is it necessary to create a separate thread for reading a serial port?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have multiple processes that need to run simultaneously: reading and reporting data coming from serial device (plugged into OSDK device), transmitting telemetry data to MSDK device, and receiving and parsing incoming data from MSDK device. I believe that data transmission is supposed to be in the main thread, so would it be proper to separate the serial read into another thread?

This is my first time working with threading.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a separate thread, you can also use non blocking functions to try to read from the serial port. However a separate thread makes some things simpler, but the needed locking again makes it more complicated. What is easier depends on the details of your task.